# How to set up php,javascript and css to allow for our finished product to be displayed within a page?

Tags: plugins, php, pages, css, javascript

hey wordpress experts,

We have coded a table using php, javascript and css which pulls up information from a text file and displays it in the browser.
We have everything working as desired when we set up our files on a local server.

However, we are trying to integrate our finished product into a page on a wordpress website.

We are using the "CSS & javascript toolbox" plugin to make a php&javascript code block and a css code block and applying it to the page in question. However, I understand that pages are stored in sql tables so this makes it hard for me to figure out how I can access the code on the server and where to put the text file on the server so that the table is displayed on the page in question and works as desired.

[image: Picture of our table]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

This will allow you to enter your PHP (and any other code) in the appropriate place to generate the content on the frontend.

Starting with a copy of your theme's current page.php file is usually a good place to start.  Modify the main area with your code, upload the file and select it as the page template in the editor screen for that page.

Answer (score 0):

We got it working. We used a plugin called the Javascript & CSS toolbox to store our individual code blocks and then we put the html code in the page content pane and it worked brilliantly.